# Writes to a brand new 16TB Exos enterprise drive are hanging for multiple minutes

Tags: hard-disk, ddrescue

I have a 16TB drive that is starting to fail.  I `ddrescue`d the first 12 terabytes of it to a 12TB WD Elements I had lying around and left the original drive unplugged until I had more storage space.  Today, I bought a brand new 16TB Seagate Exos and used `ddrescue` to copy the data I had already copied to the 12TB cheap external onto the 16TB new drive so I could start the recovery from the original 16TB onto the new 16TB already 3/4 done.

Once I started that transfer (from the 12TB to the 16TB), I noticed ddrescue kept hanging for several minutes at a time and the activity light on the external drive would go out but the activity light on the internal drive would stay on.  Curious, I opened a second terminal window and typed `time sync`.  It took 3 minutes.  I haven't witnessed that behavior since I tried to use the same flash drive as both read-write boot media and swap.

The only explanation I can think of is that the drive is taking multiple *minutes* to acknowledge a write every so often.  Even though the drive's sequential write speed is north of 200MB/s, and it hits that between these pauses, they happen frequently enough to bring `ddrescue`'s average speed (which is computed as total bytes transferred divided by total wall-clock time) below 50MB/s.

This is a brand new enterprise class drive and it's doing a sustained sequential write.  That's what hard drives are designed for.  Why is the performance so bad?  I can't blame this on filesystem overhead either because I'm writing directly to the disk without so much as a partition table in the way.  I suppose it could

Is this the drive's fault or the kernel's?  If it's the kernel's fault, how do I fix it?  If it's the drive's fault, should I consider an RMA?

Answer (score 0):

It was the kernel's fault.  The poor kernel was trying to cache every write that came its way and had to flush its buffer every now and again.  I told `ddrescue` to use direct writes on the output file (`-D` flag) and the problem went away.

Comment: Can you tell us what your sustained write speed is with `-D`?